# Largura do flexbox sendo ultrapassado

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma página com flexbox, porem um dos itens eu preciso que fiquei fixo no final da página e tenha a mesma largura dos outros itens, mas ele ultrapassa a largura padrão.

```css
html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%}
.pagina {display: flex;flex-direction: column;background: #ccc;width: 80%;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;position: relative}
.bloco1 {background: green}
.bloco2 {background: pink;position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%}
```

```html
<div class="pagina">
  <div class="bloco1">Bloco 1</div>
  <div class="bloco2">Bloco 2 - Esse é fixo no final da página</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc precisa que o elemento fique no final da página o tempo inteiro, mesmo que tiver muito conteúdo na hora do scroll esse elemento deve permanecer no mesmo lugar sem rolar junto com a página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está esperando que o div "bloco2" tenha o mesmo tamanho no seu parent, o div "pagina".

Acontece que ao usar o `display: fixed`, o tamanho do elemento em questão se comporta em relação ao *viewport*, e não seu parent, por isso ele não fica com o mesmo *width*.

Como seu parent tem `width: 80%`, você precisa usar o mesmo `width` para que ele fique com o mesmo tamanho, ao invés do `width: 100%` que ele tem atualmente, ou usar `inherit` para forçar que herde do parent:

```css
html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%}
.pagina {display: flex;flex-direction: column;background: #ccc;width: 80%;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;position: relative}
.bloco1 {background: green}
.bloco2 {background: pink;position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 80%}
```

```html
<div class="pagina">
  <div class="bloco1">Bloco 1</div>
  <div class="bloco2">Bloco 2 - Esse é fixo no final da página</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui eu usei o `width: inherit` o atributo `inherit` herda a largura do elemento pai, assim não permitindo que o um elemento filho ultrapassa o elemento pai..

```css
html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%}
.pagina {display: flex;flex-direction: column;background: #ccc;width: 80%;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;position: relative}
.bloco1 {background: green}
.bloco2 {background: pink;position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: inherit;}
```

```html
<div class="pagina">
  <div class="bloco1">Bloco 1</div>
  <div class="bloco2">Bloco 2 - Esse é fixo no final da página</div>
</div>
```